# Is there a problem with C# new modifier with different types?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following abstract class `AggregateId<T>` class now, but the type of the `Value` property there used to be a `Guid`. I changed it because I needed it to be a lot more generic, the problem is if I change the class in order to add a new Generic type, like `AggregateId<T, TValue>` it would make me perform a lot of refactoring, and I gonna end adding a lot of "noise" in the code.

The solution for this problem was change the AggregateId.Value to object type and them
using the `new modifier` with a `different type` for the classes that `inherit` from it.

```
public abstract class AggregateId<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    public object Value { get; }
    protected AggregateId(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
public class SomeClassId : AggregateId<SomeClass>
{
    public new string Value { get; }
    public MarketId(string value)
        : base(value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Now, I tried to find some information about if it is OK or why would be bad, do what I have done, but I found nothing anywhere, so my question is if there is any problem to make it the way I did?

Comment: Well, anywhere you have a variable of type `AggregateId<Something>`, you will access the `public object Value` property, and anywhere you have a variable of type `SomeClassId`, you will access the `public new string Value` property. Are you really sure you want this separation? Note, this is **even if the two variables both refer to the *same*  object instance in memory**! I know both are get-only, but you still have the opportunity in the code for them to be different.

Comment: Devil's advocate: If `object`ing makes everything so easy, why not just make *everything* object all over the place? Then all we have to do is remember (or write lots of branching code to check) what something is every time we want to use it anywhere, with anything.. Oh

Comment: The abstract class has a generic type - `T` - which isn't used anywhere in the class. The generic argument isn't used in the inherited class either. This makes it unclear what problem you're trying to solve.